# How to hide scrollbar in WebView?

Tags: html, ios, css, swift, webview

I switched to **WKWebView** because **UIWebView** is no longer recommended to be used by Apple.

Loading the HTML File from the Container in WebView using this code:

```
let webview = myWKWebViewClass.webview(for: Bundle.main.filename)
webview.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
myContainerView.addSubview(webview)
```

works quite fine.

> But the scrollbar that was hidden while using UIWebView gets displayed when I'm using WKWebView.

Using this css-style attributes is also not working *(but using UIWebView it works as expected)*:

```
 <style>
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
         display: none!important;
    }
 </style>
```

EDIT: I'm using the iPhone as real device  (not in simulator) running iOS 11.2.

[image: img]

Also tried using this Swift code:

```
webview.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
webview.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
```

It's not working at all.

Any help to hide the scrollbar would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am still looking.

Comment: iOS 16 - `webview.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false` works

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use UIScrollViewDelegate for that.

Here is example code for hide navigation bar and tool bar with scroll:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var toolBar: UIToolbar!
    @IBOutlet weak var webV: UIWebView!
    var lastOffsetY :CGFloat = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        webV.scrollView.delegate = self
        let url = "http://apple.com"
        let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
        webV.loadRequest(request)
    }

    //Delegate Methods
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView){
        lastOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView){

        let hide = scrollView.contentOffset.y > self.lastOffsetY
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(hide, animated: true)
        toolBar.hidden = hide
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try your solution later and if it is working you will get the correct-marker. @Md ...

Answer (score -2):

You can use visibility:none instead of display

Comment: visibility:none is not working either. Display:none would probably be the best method however - both solutions obviously are not working!