# Hide scrollview and scrollbar in iOS webkit webview

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scrollbar, wkwebview

I just recently migrated my iOS UIWebview objective-c to WKWebkit swift, the problem am facing now is how to hide the scroll bar from the website I loaded. I have tried anything but not of it work, please can anyone help me out.

I have followed this step here [How to hide scrollbar in WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48971789/how-to-hide-scrollbar-in-webview), both the question and accepted answer but it didn't work for me.

Please I know this might be a duplicate question but have I have tried many post to solve this none work.

```
var lastOffsetY :CGFloat = 0
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   webViewSetup()
}
```

*In webViewSetup*

```
func webViewSetup(){
  webView.scrollView.delegate = self      
}
```

*In viewWillAppear*

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let scrollView = webView.subviews[0] as? UIScrollView
        webView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: webView.frame.size.width, height: webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)
        scrollView?.bounces = false
        scrollView?.decelerationRate = .fast
        scrollView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        webView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        webView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        webView.scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
        webView.scrollView.bounces = false
    }
```

*In scrollViewDidScroll*

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x:scrollView.contentOffset.x, y:scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height), animated: false)
        }
    }

//FIXING SCROLL VIEW
//Delegate Methods
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
    lastOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}

//FIXING SCROLL VIEW
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView){
    let hide = scrollView.contentOffset.y > self.lastOffsetY
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(hide, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To turn off the web view's scrolling:

```
webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

If the code you provided is only for turning off the scrollview, that code can largely be culled down to something like this:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate {

  var webView: WKWebView!

  //configure webView
  override func loadView() {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
    view = webView
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let url = URL(string: "https://www.stackoverflow.com") {
      webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
  }
}
```